# Creating ZF2 module sub directories for Form , Service & InputFilter folders

Tags: file, module, zend-framework2, structure

I am receiving the following error

```
While attempting to create memberformmembernextpasswordchange(alias: Member\Form\member\NextPasswordChange) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.
```

I created the following file structure ( with sub directories for Forms, Input Filters and Services ) to make it easier for long term maintenance since each section of the Member module will have so much content:

```
[root@localhost src]$ find . -type d
.
./Member
./Member/Form
./Member/Form/member
./Member/Form/member/Factory
./Member/Controller
./Member/Controller/Factory
./Member/Service
./Member/Service/Form
./Member/Service/Form/Factory
./Member/Service/Factory
./Member/InputFilter
./Member/InputFilter/member
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to "link" the files the sub directories contain.  Is this even possible?

Within module.config.php I have

```
'form_elements'   => [
    'factories'  => [
        'Member\Form\member\NextPasswordChange'       => 'Member\Form\member\Factory\NextPasswordChangeFactory',
    ],
],

'input_filters'   => [
    'invokables' => [
        'Member\InputFilter\member\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\InputFilter\member\NextPasswordChange',
    ]
],

'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Member\Service\Member' => 'Member\Service\Factory\MemberFactory',
        'Member\Service\Form\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\Service\Form\Factory\NextPasswordChangeFactory',
    ]
],
```

Within MemberControllerFactory I have

```
/**
 * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
 *
 * @return MemberController
 */
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait $serviceLocator
     */
    $sl = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

    /**
     * @var \Member\Form\member\NextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange
     */
    $formNextPasswordChange = $sl->get('FormElementManager')
                    ->get('Member\Form\member\NextPasswordChange');

    /**
     * @var \Member\Service\Member $serviceMember
     */
    $serviceMember = $sl->get('Member\Service\Member');

    /**
     * @var \Member\Service\Form\NextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
     */
    $serviceNextPasswordChange = $sl->get('Member\Service\Form\NextPasswordChange');


    return new MemberController(
        $formNextPasswordChange,
        $serviceMember,
        $serviceNextPasswordChange
    );
}
```

The header section of MemberController contains

```
namespace Member\Controller;

use Member\Form\member\NextPasswordChange as FormNextPasswordChange;
use Member\Service\Member as ServiceMember;
use Member\Service\Form\NextPasswordChange as ServiceNextPasswordChange;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

/**
 * Class MemberController
 *
 * @package Member\Controller
 *
 * @method Request getRequest()
 */
class MemberController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var FormNextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange
     */
    private $formNextPasswordChange;

    /**
     * @var ServiceMember $serviceMember
     */
    private $serviceMember;

    /**
     * @var ServiceNextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
     */
    private $serviceNextPasswordChange;

    /**
     * @param FormNextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange
     * @param ServiceMember          $serviceMember
     */
    public function __construct(
        FormNextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange,
        ServiceMember $serviceMember,
        ServiceNextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
    )
    {
        $this->formNextPasswordChange = $formNextPasswordChange;

        $this->serviceMember = $serviceMember;

        $this->serviceNextPasswordChange = $serviceNextPasswordChange;
    }
```

Comment: Can your autoloader handle the lowercase 'member' directory? Is `class_exists()' able to find those classes?

Comment: When I changed \Form\member to upper case PHPSTorm gives me the error 'undefined name space'

Comment: The error now reads: While attempting to create memberformmembernextpasswordchange(alias: Member\Form\Member\NextPasswordChange) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.

Comment: This references: $formNextPasswordChange = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get('Member\Form\Member\NextPasswordChange');

Comment: The module.config.php reference is: 'Member\Form\Member\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\Form\Member\Factory\NextPasswordChangeFactory',

Comment: After more tweaking the error has changed again.  I need to start a new question since the code here isn't up to date.